# iPhone display of incoming calls and texts

Tags: iphone

My iPhone displays phone numbers on incoming calls. How do I get it to display the name of the caller

Answer (score 2):

iPhone will displays the name of the caller only if the incoming number matches with that of any of the saved contacts.

Answer (score 1):

To add the person as a Contact so the caller ID displays as his/her name:

- Go to the **Contacts** App in your iPhone.
- Create a new contact by clicking the + icon at the top right.
- Enter a *First name* and other information.
- Tap the *add phone* (Green + icon) and add the phone number for the person. Repeat for other numbers such as Home and Work.

Now when the person calls you will see his/her name as a caller ID.

You can also do the reverse from the **Phone** app.

- Tap the *Recents* icon at the bottom.
- Tap the *info* icon (looks like an 'i' in a circle)
- Tap *Create New Contact*
- Add the person's name and, if needed, change the phone number type.